# View Source after scripts have run

Tags: google-chrome

I have noticed that, in Chrome, "View Source" gives you the pre-processed code and Inspect element the processed code. Is there any way to get the processed code in plain text format?

Thanks

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML` via the console.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Add-on like this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pendule/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi